# Collect file names into `Vec<str>`

Tags: rust

How do I collect file names from a directory into something like `Vec<&str>`:

```
let paths = fs::read_dir("...")
    .unwrap()
    .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
    .map(|e| e.path().to_str());
```

Also, how to make it return an empty list if the folder doesn't exist?

Comment: `match` on your `read_dir` call? This is where `unwrap()` is assuming everything is fine, which it might not be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fs::read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) returns an iterator that iterates over [`Result<DirEntry>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html), which exposes a [`DirEntry::path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path) method. This method returns a [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html), which owns the buffer that contains the filename.

In your original sample, you have tried to convert these into `&str` - there are two problems with that:

1. `path()` returns a `PathBuf`, which you take a reference from (via `to_str()`) but you do not store the `PathBuf` anywhere, so compilation fails with this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         .map(|e| e.path().to_str());
  |                  --------^^^^^^^^^
  |                  |
  |                  returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
  |                  temporary value created here
```

2. `to_str()` returns `Option<str>` - if the Path contained any non-UTF8 characters, then it returns `None`. You would have ended up with a `Vec` containing `Option<&str>`.

I would suggest collecting them into a `Vec<PathBuf>`, which is as simple as:

```rust
    let paths = fs::read_dir("...")
        .unwrap()
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .map(|e| e.path())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

If you really need them as strings, you can use:

```rust
    let paths = fs::read_dir("...")
        .unwrap()
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .map(|e| e.path().to_string_lossy().into_owned())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

`to_string_lossy()` will convert the path into a string, replacing any non-utf8 characters with a replacement character. It returns a `Cow<&str>` - which may or may not actually own the string. To ensure that an owned string is returned, we call `into_owned()`.

Finally, to make it return an empty list if the folder does not exist, you could use something like this:

```rust
    let paths : Vec<PathBuf> = match fs::read_dir("/tmsp") {
    
        Err(e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::NotFound => Vec::new(),
        
        Err(e) => panic!("Unexpected Error! {:?}", e),
        
        Ok(entries) => entries.filter_map(|e| e.ok())
            .map(|e| e.path())
            .collect()
            

    };
```

The above sample would panic if any error other than `NotFound` occurred - in reality you would probably handle that case more gracefully.

Comment: Thank you! I had to add `.collect()` to the last expression to get `Vec<String>`.

Comment: @vasily Oops completely forgot that! I have added that to the answer

Comment: @vasily Note that converting `PathBuf` to `String` is a lossy operation. In general, the resulting string can't be used to locate the file again, so it's only useful in a very limited set of circumstances. As stated in this answer, it's a lot more likely you want a `Vec<PathBuf>` instead.